# Qt 5.14.2 - compile issue

Tags: qt

Environment - RHEL 6, x86_64 machine / Also getting same error for MAC 10.12

```
qtbase/configure -top-level --prefix=/opt/local/Qt-5.13.2 -skip qtconnectivityy
 -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtwayland -skip qtsensors -skip qtmacextras -skip qtwinextras -qt-xcb -opensource -confirm-license -icu -v -release -I /opt/local/include -L /opt/local/lib -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtcanvas3d
```

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dquick qml quick 3dquickextras
cd wireframe/ && ( test -e Makefile || qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
qt3d/examples/qt3d/wireframe/wireframe.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dquick qml quick 3dquickextras
make[3]: *** [sub-multiviewport-make_first] Error 3
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dquick qml quick 3dquickextras
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dquick qml quick 3dquickextras
make[3]: *** [sub-simple-qml-make_first] Error 3
make[3]: *** [sub-wireframe-make_first] Error 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The Qt3D example you are trying to build depends on 3dquick, qml, quick and 3dquickextras. I believe that you disabled them with `-skip qtdeclarative`. You can try adding `-nomake examples` to avoid building the examples.

Comment: Yeah, skipping `qtdeclerative` does disable the QML stuff.